# Accessing to information in a ".txt" file and go to a determinated row

Tags: c++, file-io, newline, text-parsing, getline

When accessing a text file, I want to read from a specific line. Let's suppose that my file has 1000 rows and I want to read row 330. Each row has a different number of characters and could possibly be quite long (let's say around 100,000,000 characters per row).  I'm thinking `fseek()` can't be used effectively here.

I was thinking about a loop to track linebreaks, but I don't know how exactly how to implement it, and I don't know if that would be the best solution.

Can you offer any help?

Comment: I think you mean "determined."  :)

Comment: off-topic, but "I have a doubt" is an English mistake. You mean, "I have a question" or "I have a problem I am trying to solve". "To doubt" is to be skeptical of an assertion. For example, "He said it weighs 10 kg but I doubt it." or "I have no doubt that you can lift it."

Comment: @tenfour: Sorry, it is not a mistake at all.  It is just standard usage in a different version of English than you are used to.

Comment: "I have a doubt." is not standard usage for a English native speaker in any locale.

Comment: @tenfour: You are clearly not familiar with how English is used in India.  See http://chaileaves.blogspot.com/2007/03/do-needful.html for more.

Comment: My comment was for thomas' best interest. I am familiar with how English is used in Brussels for example and much of it is misuse of English based on the speaker's native language. For example Dutch-speaking people often refer to "the magazine standing on the table". It's not wrong enough to be misunderstood, but it is wrong enough to be corrected. "I have a doubt." falls into the same category. I don't refer to the dictionary for what's "right", but just because people say it doesn't make it correct.

Comment: thanks tenfour! thought it's an off-topic it's also usefull and I really appreciatte your coment! :)

Answer (score 3):

Unless you have some kind of index saying "line M begins at position N" in the file, you have to read characters from the file and count newlines until you find the desired line.

You can easily read lines using `std::getline` if you want to save the contents of each line, or `std::istream::ignore` if you want to discard the contents of the lines you read until you find the desired line.

Comment: Yeap! Suppose that when my file has been written the end of every row is written as "myfile<<endl;" so you would know where every row starts. So the idea is accessing my ".txt" file and make with a loop as many linebreaks as I want, any idea how would it be???

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to know where row 330 starts in an arbitrary text file without scanning the whole file, finding the line breaks, and then counting.

If you only need to do this once, then scan.  If you need to do it many times, then you can scan once, and build up a data structure listing where all of the lines start.  Now you can figure out where to seek to to read just that line.  If you're still just thinking about how to organize data, I would suggest using some other type of data structure for random access.  I can't recommend which one without knowing the actual problem that you are trying to solve.

Comment: Yeap! Suppose that when your file has been written the end of every row is written as "myfile<<endl;" so you would know where every row starts.

Comment: @thomas: At the time you are writing the file you could figure out where the newlines went.  But if you don't save that information at that time, then when you're reading you have no idea where they now are.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to scan the file and count the \n occurrences since you find the desired line. If this is a frequent operation, and you are the only one you write the file, you can possibly mantain an index file containing such information side by side with the one containing the data, a sort of "poor-man-index", but can save a lot of time.

Comment: The problem is that if I have to read all the information in the row the process would be too long. Think that every row has 10000000000 characters. And if I want to get the ten first different characters of the row 330 it's not sense to read all the different previous lines, right?? Any idea??

Comment: It does make sense, because there's no other way without a pre-built index. A line break is nothing special; you could just as well be counting of occurrences of the letter 'k'. You must scan the file. A "line" is a specialty defined by the text file format, not intrinsically defined by the filesystem.

Answer (score 1):

Create an index on the file. You can do this "lazily" but as you read a buffer full you may as well scan it for each character.

If it is a text file on Windows that uses a 2-byte '\n' then the number of characters you read to the point where the newline occurs will not be the offset. So what you should do is a "seek" after each call to getline().

something like:

```
std::vector< off_t > lineNumbers;
std::string line;
lineNumbers.push_back(0); // first line begins at 0
while( std::getline( ifs, line ) )
{
   lineNumbers.push_back(ifs.tellg());
}
```

last value will tell you where EOF is.

Answer (score 0):

Try running [fgets](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/fgets/) in a loop

```
/* fgets example */
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
   FILE * pFile;
   char mystring [100];

   pFile = fopen ("myfile.txt" , "r");
   if (pFile == NULL) perror ("Error opening file");
   else {
     fgets (mystring , 100 , pFile);
     puts (mystring);
     fclose (pFile);
   }
   return 0;
}
```